# Web Scraping Values on Google Search Results Page. Python, BeautifulSoup, Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, google-search

I am new to Python and am trying to make a series of programs to text my phone the performance of stock market indices. I have a few programs working with limited functionality, and I believe they'd be improved if the data could be scraped from google, which I have not been able to do so far. The values I am trying to pull are at the top of the results page every time, almost in a table of some sort. At the bottom, I have a snip attached with the value I am trying to scrape.

Here is the portion of the code I have for the web scraping portion currently. I am using beautiful soup and requests.

```
import bs4
import requests

res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&sxsrf=ALeKk00d7WrRTMvmhypG20E5MOEWpRwKlw%3A1601591747498&ei=w1l2X52DHoPatAXElILQDg&q=nasdaq+composite&oq=nasd&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgwIIxAnEJ0CEEYQ-gEyBAgjECcyBAgjECcyCggAELEDEIMBEEMyCggAELEDEIMBEEMyCAgAELEDEIMBMgcIABCxAxBDMgcIABCxAxBDMgcIABCxAxBDMgoIABCxAxCDARBDOgQIABBHOgUIABCxAzoHCCMQ6gIQJzoHCCMQJxCdAjoECAAQQ1DszQ5Y9tkOYPjkDmgBcAJ4BYABqQOIAZ4NkgEJMS43LjEuMC4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdperABCsgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab')
type(res)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
type(soup)

Current_Level = soup.find(class_='IsqQVc_NprOob_XcVN5d')

print (Current_Level)
```

The link leads to page if you googled "Nasdaq composite". The class I am using for `soup.find()` is aligned with the value when you right click - inspect the value on the web page.

Open to all solutions to get this value. Thanks for all of your help, greatly appreciated!

[Image of the value I'm trying to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uLoi.png)

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](//developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](//policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can get the value.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

url_to_scrape = "https://www.google.com/search?q=nasdaq+composite&oq=nasdaq+composite&aqs=chrome.0.0l8.5126j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"

try:
    client_page = requests.get(url_to_scrape)
except:
    print("Request aborted due to unknown reason!")

page_html = client_page.text
client_page.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser") 
 
nasdaqValue = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd"})
print(nasdaqValue[0].text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked great. Have a follow up question. How did you get the value "BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd"? When I inspect the page, I can't find any class with this value, and I'm really confused because the other comment on here as well used the same class.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the class name `BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get(
    "https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&sxsrf=ALeKk00d7WrRTMvmhypG20E5MOEWpRwKlw%3A1601591747498&ei=w1l2X52DHoPatAXElILQDg&q=nasdaq+composite&oq=nasd&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgwIIxAnEJ0CEEYQ-gEyBAgjECcyBAgjECcyCggAELEDEIMBEEMyCggAELEDEIMBEEMyCAgAELEDEIMBMgcIABCxAxBDMgcIABCxAxBDMgcIABCxAxBDMgoIABCxAxCDARBDOgQIABBHOgUIABCxAzoHCCMQ6gIQJzoHCCMQJxCdAjoECAAQQ1DszQ5Y9tkOYPjkDmgBcAJ4BYABqQOIAZ4NkgEJMS43LjEuMC4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdperABCsgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab"
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

# Using `.split()` to remove `+159.00 (1.42%)` from the output
Current_Level = soup.find(class_="BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd").text.split('+')[0]
print(Current_Level)
```

Output:

```
+257.47
```

Edit:

If you call `soup.prettify()` you see that the data is under the class `BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
print(soup.prettify())
...
...
<div>
      <div>
       <div>
        <div class="kCrYT">
         <div>
          <div>
           <div>
            <div class="BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd">
             <div>
              <div class="BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd">
               11,332.49
               <span class="rQMQod AWuZUe">
                +257.47 (2.32%)
               </span>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
...
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked great. Have a follow up question. How did you get the value "BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd"? When I inspect the page, I can't find any class with this value, and I'm really confused because the other comment on here as well used the same class.

Comment: @JG71273 If you print the actuall `soup` object, you see that the data is under the class `BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd`

Comment: I'm having trouble taking your meaning. Are you saying add the line:     
print(soup) ? I tried that, and got None as a return text.                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                         If you meant differently, would you provide a minimal code example for me to see? Sorry for all the questions, I'm still very new to all of this. Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: Ran it; makes sense. Thanks for your additional help on this. greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you're using `user-agent` otherwise Google will block your request eventually thus you'll receive a completely different HTML with some sort of an error that will contain different selectors and elements. Check [what is your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

`Update 2022.03.10`:

If this script was throwing an error to past users who saw this answer, it's because of two reasons:

1. old `user-agent`. Because of it, Google or other website might assume that if request being made with an old `use-agent`, it's likely a script or a bot that sends a request.
2. CSS selector was changed by Google. Because of it, old selector can't be recognized by `beautifulsoup`.

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Stock-price-python-bs4-requests#main.py):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"
}

params = {
  "q": "Nasdaq composite",
  "hl": "en"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params).text, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('.wT3VGc').text)

# 13,089.08
```

Comment: love this disclaimer